# See actual response instead of "This request has no response data available"

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, debugging, xmlhttprequest, web-inspector

When there is something that fires **Ajax** or **XHR Request**, sometimes, if the `php` (or other server side script) has some fatal error, the **Chrome** browser returns such response:

[image]

However, if we manually open that failing url, then the browser shows the output from that page (i.e. `Fatal error - $variable not defined` or whatever ).
How to see that actual response message in chrome, instead of the `500 (Internal Server Error)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but if someone needs to get more details about that call, hook a function into `AJAX/XHR` request (define this in chrome `console`):

```
(function() {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            console.log(this);
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

After that, when triggering the AJAX action, the `console` will show the details.